# A Query of In-Memory vs. DB/Cache Performance for 200,000 Item Lookup List

Tags: sql, .net, linq, caching

Given a value (as a key, if you like), look up other values associated with that value, as in columns in a DB table.

I need to do hundreds, and preferably, thousands of these lookups every second.

What I do now:

- I use EF/LINQ against an MS SQL DB on the same machine (VS 2012/13).
- I return any data I have already looked up recently (see below)
- If *not* in 'cache' above, I proceed to:
- I look up the data in the row (each row is 1-2KB (small)), and return to app, and add to 'cache'.
- If I have not looked that value up recently, I add it to an in-memory list ('cache'), so the next time.
- The cache increases in size as time goes by.

200,000+ items at 2kb will certainly fit in memory easily enough, but will looking things up in it 1,000/sec+ cause other problems with the system's operation/responsiveness?

Am I even making a 'cache' the right way?

I expect the amount of data to lookup to increase greatly over time, so understanding what to look for in performance to signal switching to a suitable strategy is key.

Comment: you aren't going to use LINQ to "search" for these cached items are you?  Surely a `Dictionary` would be a better option no?

Comment: Please stop using signatures and salutations in your posts. [Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: When you say you're doing "thousands of these lookups every second", is that because you're literally getting that many requests for data from various clients, or is your system doing a `for` loop across large data structures and looking up each item one at a time?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, It's a syslog server (UDP 514), so in a way, it is push, but since I need to loop through the ones available, it also ends up being a For (sort of)... I throw the entries into a message queue to avoid losing any during downtime/updates, etc. So reading the queue ends up in an async loop, in a way... Right now, I seem to be max'ing out at 800 msgs/second (taking from the msgqueue) , but I know I can do it faster. MemoryCache looks fantastic, as it allows cps on memory and age.

Comment: @PatTrainor: Sounds like a fun problem to solve. Can you tell where most of your time is being spent? (I'd guess it's in evaluating your SQL queries.) Since these are inherently asynchronous operations, I wonder if you could take advantage of async EF queries and let your program process multiple items concurrently? It seems like Reactive Extensions could give you some nice tools, too.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Oh, brevity sucks... I am not taking the objeccts/instances from an SQL DB, but from a mesgqueue. I run many parser threads at once, and they all take from the queue as soon as they need something to do, and run idle, waiting for .BeginPeek when not working. each syslog event is a custom message, wrapped in a standard syslog UDP datagram. messagequeue is excellent at converting to XML & marshaling each object, and preparing them in FIFO order on disk for later retrieval. Next thing for me is to fire up MemoryCache! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... will looking things up in it 1,000/sec+ cause other problems with the system's operation/responsiveness?

Not as such: `Dictionary<>`s and `MemoryCache`s can handle hundreds of thousands of such lookups per second.

But the fact that you're doing the same thing so many times might be a code smell. You may want to consider whether you're missing an opportunity to group your data in some way, so that you're doing a lookup based on a key that is common to all the items that are being retrieved.

Regardless, you'll definitely want to batch the lookups when the time comes to query the database, because hitting the database thousands of times *will* mess with your performance.

Comment: The way I do it now is like I said in the OP, but the detail is that I grab 100 events at a time from the mesg queue, into a list(), then the parsers (each on a different thread, by default 1 per 'core') take from that list. When the parsers become idle I replenish. I'd never even see MemoryCache before, but the MSDN page makes it look very desirable to me. Also, a big part of my question was/is what structure is best to use. I am using a blockingQueue() because I can do FIFO. I was under the impression (incorrectly?) that dictionary was not FIFO-style...

Comment: @PatTrainor: While it isn't part of their documented, guaranteed behavior, I believe Dictionaries in .NET do in fact keep their entries ordered according to insertion, so you could remove the first N entries every so often, and you'd end up with FIFO behavior. But I agree that MemoryCache is almost certainly a better fit for what you're doing. It has concurrency, automatic memory management, expiration management, etc.